# ngRoute wont load template correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to make a website with fully responsive and One page design.

I setup Angular Route to my html template. But slider etc. wont work correctly with templateUrl

AppRouter.js

```
 angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/anasayfa.html',
            controller: 'AnasayfaController'
        })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

app.js

```
    angular.module('Wooty', [
    'ngRoute',
    'appRoutes',
    'anasayfaCtrl',
    'indexCtrl'
]);

angular.module('indexCtrl', []).controller('IndexController', function($scope,$http,$location,$rootScope) {
    $scope.Test = 'Çalıştı'
});
```

index.html parts

body definition

```
<body class="animsition" ng-app="Wooty" ng-controller="IndexController">
```

ngView part

```
<div ng-view="Wooty"></div>
```

anasayfa.html @ views folder

Only slide part

```
<section class="section-slide">
    <div class="wrap-slick1 rs2-slick1">
        <div class="slick1">
            <div class="item-slick1 bg-overlay1" style="background-image: url(images/slide-05.jpg);" data-thumb="images/thumb-01.jpg" data-caption="Women’s Wear">
                <div class="container h-full">
                    <div class="flex-col-c-m h-full p-t-100 p-b-60 respon5">
                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="fadeInDown" data-delay="0">
                            <span class="ltext-202 txt-center cl0 respon2">
                                Women Collection 2018
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="fadeInUp" data-delay="800">
                            <h2 class="ltext-104 txt-center cl0 p-t-22 p-b-40 respon1">
                                New arrivals
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="zoomIn" data-delay="1600">
                            <a href="product.html" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn2 p-lr-15 trans-04">
                                Shop Now
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item-slick1 bg-overlay1" style="background-image: url(images/slide-06.jpg);" data-thumb="images/thumb-02.jpg" data-caption="Men’s Wear">
                <div class="container h-full">
                    <div class="flex-col-c-m h-full p-t-100 p-b-60 respon5">
                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rollIn" data-delay="0">
                            <span class="ltext-202 txt-center cl0 respon2">
                                Men New-Season
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="lightSpeedIn" data-delay="800">
                            <h2 class="ltext-104 txt-center cl0 p-t-22 p-b-40 respon1">
                                Jackets & Coats
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="slideInUp" data-delay="1600">
                            <a href="product.html" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn2 p-lr-15 trans-04">
                                Shop Now
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item-slick1 bg-overlay1" style="background-image: url(images/slide-07.jpg);" data-thumb="images/thumb-03.jpg" data-caption="Men’s Wear">
                <div class="container h-full">
                    <div class="flex-col-c-m h-full p-t-100 p-b-60 respon5">
                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rotateInDownLeft" data-delay="0">
                            <span class="ltext-202 txt-center cl0 respon2">
                                Men Collection 2018
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rotateInUpRight" data-delay="800">
                            <h2 class="ltext-104 txt-center cl0 p-t-22 p-b-40 respon1">
                                NEW SEASON
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rotateIn" data-delay="1600">
                            <a href="product.html" class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn2 p-lr-15 trans-04">
                                Shop Now
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-slick1-dots p-lr-10"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Slides wont work just loaded like images top to top. Not effects works when seperates index.html and anasayfa.html

But the features on index.html is working well.(sidebar and navbar)

Answer (score 0):

do you have any errors in console ? 
maybe "AnasayfaController" controller isnt loading properly ? 
if you can show us   "AnasayfaController"  controller it will be easier to help you .

Comment: AnasayfaController is empty like this angular.module('anasayfaCtrl',[]).controller('AnasayfaController',function ($scope,$http){
    
});

Comment: hey , first put an alert in AnasayfaController  make sure that the controller is loaded .